# Escaping Scratch-Built XQuery in Java

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I'm working on an application that will build and execute XQueries on a MarkLogic server.  I'll need to escape some input strings to make sure they don't screw-up the query.  Is there any existing Java code that handles this?  I'd like to avoid re-inventing this wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in language features: XQuery provides external variables, and the XCC API can set them from Java. See http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/overview-summary.html for examples, under "Passing Variables With Queries". Here's a simple one:

```
Session session = contentSource.newSession("mydatabase");
Request request = session.newAdhocQuery(
    "xquery version \"1.0-ml\";\n" +
    "declare variable $myvar as xs:string external;\n" +
    "data($myvar)");

// create Variable "myvar", bind to Request, ignore return value
request.setNewVariable ("myvar", ValueType.XS_STRING, "Some string value");

// "$myvar as xs:string" will be defined at query run time
ResultSequence rs = session.submitRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a library like XQJ it has the ability to bind external XQuery variables. In this way the library should take care of escaping any sensitive values and injecting them into your XQuery. There is an XQJ library for MarkLogic available from xqj.net.